# How to do non-greedy parsing in ash with grep without Perl

Tags: regex, grep, ash

Hi I'm trying to parse through a folder structure and just have the first two folders in a directory passed to a variable. Right now I'm using the regex '/.*?/.*?/' which works fine except my version of ash on OpenWRT doesn't support Perl and thus the "? are ignored. How can I fix this?

```
var2=$(echo "$TR_TORRENT_DIR" | grep -Eio '\/.*?\/.*?\/')
echo $var2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your regex more specific.

In general, use of non-greedy modifiers is a red flag. It should make you think about whether you can rewrite your regex in a more specific way (so it doesn't matter whether a quantifier is greedy or not).

In this case the problem is `.*` (another flag), which matches far too much.

If you use `[^/]` instead of `.`, you avoid all problems:

```
/[^/]*/[^/]*/
```

will match the first two components and nothing more. (Also, there's no need to escape `/`; it's not special in a regex.)

Comment: Thanks. I figured non-greedy was a red flag but I'm just starting out with Regex. Thank you very much!